# FastAPI: Task was destroyed but it is pending

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, fastapi, tornado

I've been fighting asyncio + FastAPI for the last 48 hours. Any help would be appreciated. I'm registering an `on_gift` handler that parses gifts I care about and appends them to `gift_queue`. I'm then pulling them out in a while loop later in the code to send to the websocket.

The goal is to block the main thread until the client disconnects. Then we can do cleanup. It appears that the cleanup is being ran but I'm seeing this error after the first request:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-12' coro=<WebSocketProtocol13._receive_frame_loop() running at /Users/zane/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py:1106> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /Users/zane/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:687, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f9558a53af0>()]> cb=[IOLoop.add_future.<locals>.<lambda>() at /Users/zane/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:687]>
```

```py
@router.websocket('/donations')
async def scan_donations(websocket: WebSocket, username):
    await websocket.accept()

    client = None
    gift_queue = []
    try:
        client = TikTokLiveClient(unique_id=username,
                                  sign_api_key=api_key)

        def on_gift(event: GiftEvent):
            gift_cost = 1

            print('[DEBUG] Could not find gift cost for {}. Using 1.'.format(
                    event.gift.extended_gift.name))

            try:
                if event.gift.streakable:
                    if not event.gift.streaking:
                        if gift_cost is not None:
                            gift_total_cost = gift_cost * event.gift.repeat_count
                            # if it cost less than 99 coins, skip it
                            if gift_total_cost < 99:
                                return

                        gift_queue.append(json.dumps({
                            "type": 'tiktok_gift',
                            "data": dict(name=event.user.nickname)
                        }))
                else:
                    if gift_cost < 99:
                        return

                    gift_queue.append(json.dumps({
                        'type': 'tiktok_gift',
                        'data': dict(name=event.user.nickname)
                    }))
            except:
                print('[DEBUG] Could not parse gift event: {}'.format(event))

        client.add_listener('gift', on_gift)

        await client.start()

        while True:
            if gift_queue:
                gift = gift_queue.pop(0)
                await websocket.send_text(gift)

                del gift
            else:
                try:
                    await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.receive_text(), timeout=1)
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    continue
    except ConnectionClosedOK:
        pass
    except ConnectionClosedError as e:
        print("[ERROR] TikTok: ConnectionClosedError {}".format(e))
        pass
    except FailedConnection as e:
        print("[ERROR] TikTok: FailedConnection {}".format(e))
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print("[ERROR] TikTok: {}".format(e))
        pass
    finally:
        print("[DEBUG] TikTok: Stopping listener...")
        if client is not None:
            print('Stopping TTL')
            client.stop()
        await websocket.close()
```

To add:

I can see

```
[ERROR] TikTok: 1000
[DEBUG] TikTok: Stopping listener...
Stopping TTL
```

Once I disconnect in Postman. It seems that something is not exiting cleanly. I have a `scan_chat` function which is nearly identical and I don't get these errors.

Comment: Likely to do with `asyncio.wait_for(websocket.receive_text(), timeout=1)` and the websocket connection not closing/exiting properly when the timeout is reached.

Comment: I tried the `wait_for` as part of another recommendation. I need to use `websocket.receive_text()` in order for the WebSocket disconnect exceptions to be raised. I'm pretty stuck here, I'm going to port it all to JavaScript instead

Comment: Moving to JS made this much easier. I used socket.io, ws, and node-fetch for the final workaround.